# WebDriverException: Message: 'wires' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using Firefox 47.0.1 and selenium 2.53.1
After I did all the steps I got the error below.

setting on py file:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox"
```

**Error:**

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'wires' executable may have wrong permissions.
```

Appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: I don't recomand to use Firefox WebDriver,try to use ChromeWeb Driver.Because FirFox WebDriver tends to update even when you do Crawling, So it will occur Version compatibility problems even the program started to run correctly.

Comment: I've hit exactly the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution for this issue? I'm on El Captain with Firefox 49 and having similar problem. Also using `marionette` and passing the path to `firefox` from /Applications/Firefox.app/...